# Why are morphological operations on 3D images so slow in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, itk, mitk

I am running Matlab 2016a and use imopen on a 301x301x271 logical image.
Example code:

```
A = randi([0 1], 301, 301, 271);
A = logical(A);
se = strel('sphere',12);
tic;
A = imopen(A, se);
toc;
```

Elapsed time is 294.313918 seconds.

Using all 4 CPU cores. Calling the same code from within a function uses only one core for some reason (600s).

```
function CreateExample()
...code...
end
```

Doing the same thing using MITK (which basically just uses itkBinaryMorphologicalOpeningImageFilter) takes less than 10 seconds.

Any ideas for optimizations? Gpuarray is not possible because it's 3D.

Comment: Try using the profiler in order to find out what is taking so long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to run both the situations you mentioned (in a script and within a function), and in both cases, I noticed that MATLAB uses multiple cores (4 in my case too), and so I cannot reproduce this behavior.

However, I believe one of the major reasons that MATLAB is slower than ITK for a sphere is that a 3D sphere is not decomposed into smaller simpler shapes.

```
SE = strel('disk', 12);
sum(SE.Neighborhood(:))
```

is 697, which is the number of 'on' pixels in the 3D sphere.

The cube on the other hand is decomposed, meaning:

```
SE = strel('cube', 25);
% The decompose method replaces one cube with three 3D lines, 
% applied repeatedly over the volume.
seq = SE.decompose() 
sum(seq(1).Neighborhood)
sum(seq(2).Neighborhood)
sum(seq(3).Neighborhood)
```

This reduces the number of comparisons to be made from 25 cubed to 3 times 25, which is probably what ITK does to optimize this.

I would be curious to know if you use a cube, like 'se = strel('cube',25);' instead. I'm fairly certain it is much faster. If that is true, you could investigate decomposing the sphere and using it instead, for example:

Vaz, M. S., Kiraly, A. P., & Mersereau, R. M. (2007). Multi-level decomposition of Euclidean spheres. In Proc. Int. Symp. Math. Morphology (ISMM) (pp. 461-472).